# Sencha Touch 2: itemtap on IE not targeting divs

Tags: javascript, cordova, internet-explorer, sencha-touch, windows-8.1

I'm working on a Cordova hybrid app and currently facing issues on Windows 8.1 with Sencha Touch 2. I got a some divs on a listitem with some subelements. I defined a tap listener. This works fine with Android and IOS, but this doesn't work on Win8.1 with Internet Explorer. I'm always getting the above lying listitem-element not the clicked div-containers.

This is the simplified example:

view:

```
Ext.define( 'App.view.MyDataView', {

xtype: 'mydataview',
extend:  Ext.dataview.List ,

config: {

    inline: false,
    title: "myTitle",

    scrollToTopOnRefresh: false,

    cls: 'MyDataView',
    itemCls: 'MyDataViewItem',
    pressedCls: 'MyDataViewItemPressed',
    grouped: true,

    listeners: {
        tap: {
            element: 'element',
            //delegate: '.something',

            fn: function (e)
            {
                console.log(e.target.className)
            }
        }
    },
    deferEmptyText: false,
    infinite: true,

    variableHeights: true,
    itemTpl: new Ext.XTemplate(
        [

                            '<div class="red" style="background-color:red;width:50%">',
                'red',
                '<div class="black" style="background-color:black;width:80%">',
                    '<div class="blue" style="background-color:blue;width:30%">blue</div>',
                'black</div>',
            '</div>'
        ].join( '' ),
        {
            compiled: true,
            getInteractable: function() {},
            //some member functions here...

        }
    )
}
});
```

e.target on tap listener always give me following:

```
<div class="x-unsized x-list-item WorkingHoursDataViewItem x-has-height x-list-item-tpl" id="ext-simplelistitem-85" style="height: 42px !important; min-height: 42px !important; transform: translate3d(0px, 264px, 0px);">
  <div class="x-unsized x-list-disclosure x-item-hidden" id="ext-component-233" style="display: none !important;"></div>
  <div class="x-innerhtml" id="ext-element-815">
        <div class="red" style="width: 50%; background-color: red;">
              red
           <div class="black" style="width: 80%; background-color:black;">
               <div class="blue" style="width: 30%; background-color:blue;">
                          blue
                          </div>
                     </div>
                    black
                  </div>
             </div>
              </div>
           </div>
        </div>
     </div>
  </div>
```

I browsed alot through event, e, target but there is no reference to the clicked div container :/

Thanks in advance!

//edit: simplified example
// it is related to grouped:true -> if i comment this out everything works as expected

Answer (score 4, accepted):

fixed it - if grouped: true was set, it caused this unexpected results on IE.

Workaround: after showing view: list.updateGrouped()

Comment: Another workaround - use a browser that actually supports standards properly.

Comment: like I wrote: I'm developing a Cordova hybrid app for Windows, so there is no option to use a different WebView instead of Microsofts